# Correct use of split()

Tags: python, split

I'm trying to split lines of text and store key information in a dictionary.

For example I have lines that look like:

```
Lasal_00010 H293|H293_08936 42.37   321 164 8   27  344 37  339 7e-74    236
Lasal_00010 SSEG|SSEG_00350 43.53   317 156 9   30  342 42  339 7e-74    240
```

For the first line, my key will be "Lasal_00010", and the value I'm storing is "H293".

My current code works fine for this case, but when I encounter a line like:

```
Lasal_00030 SSCG|pSCL4|SSCG_06461   27.06   218 83  6   37  230 35  200 5e-11   64.3
```

my code will not store the string "SSCG".

Here is my current code:

```
dataHash = {}
with open(fasta,'r') as f:
    for ln in f:
        query = ln.split('\t')[0]   
        query.strip()   
        tempValue = ln.split('\t')[1]
        value = tempValue.split('|')[0]
        value.strip()
        if not dataHash.has_key(query):
            dataHash[query] = ''
        else:
            dataHash[query] = value
for x in dataHash:
    print x + " " + str(dataHash[x])
```

I believe I am splitting the line incorrectly in the case with two vertical bars. But I'm confused as to where my problem is. Shouldn't "SSCG" be the value I get when I write `value = tempValue.split('|')[0]`? Can someone explain to me how split works or what I'm missing?

Comment: Do you not care about anything after the first `|` character?

Comment: Right now I don't, but I'm going to need that information eventually when I expand my code.

Comment: Why do you store an empty string if `query` is not yet found in `dataHash`, but the value otherwise? Your code *should* handle `Lasal_00030` just fine, but if `SSCG` is the *first* `Lasal_00030` line, all you do is store an empty string.

Comment: @MartijnPieters Yeah, that was the problem in my code. I should not have been storing the empty string

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Split on the first pipe, then on the space:

```
with open(fasta,'r') as f:
    for ln in f:
        query, value = ln.partition('|')[0].split()
```

I used `str.partition()` here as you only need to split once.

Your code makes assumptions on where tabs are being used; by splitting on the first pipe *first* we get to ignore the rest of the line altogether, making it a lot simpler to split the first from the second column.

Demo:

```
>>> lines = '''\
... Lasal_00010 H293|H293_08936 42.37   321 164 8   27  344 37  339 7e-74    236
... Lasal_00010 SSEG|SSEG_00350 43.53   317 156 9   30  342 42  339 7e-74    240
... Lasal_00030 SSCG|pSCL4|SSCG_06461   27.06   218 83  6   37  230 35  200 5e-11   64.3
... '''
>>> for ln in lines.splitlines(True):
...     query, value = ln.partition('|')[0].split()
...     print query, value
... 
Lasal_00010 H293
Lasal_00010 SSEG
Lasal_00030 SSCG
```

However, your code works too, up to a point, albeit less efficiently. Your real problem is with:

```
if not dataHash.has_key(query):
    dataHash[query] = ''
else:
    dataHash[query] = value
```

This really means: First time I see `query`, store an empty string, otherwise store `value`. I am not sure why you do this; if there are no other lines starting with `Lasal_00030`, all you have is an empty value in the dictionary. If that wasn't the intention, just store the value:

```
dataHash[query] = value
```

No `if` statement.

Note that `dict.has_key()` has been deprecated; it is better to use `in` to test for a key:

```
if query not in dataHash:
```

Comment: I tried using using `partition()` like you suggested, but it didn't work.  I still don't get "SSCG" stored.

Comment: @mookamooka: define "didn't work". Threw an exception, didn't solve your problem?

Comment: @Martjin Pieters When I try printing out the value from the dictionary I create, I still get no value stored for Lasal_00030.  I'm expecting "SSCG" to be printed

Comment: @mookamooka: then why do you store `''` when the key is not yet in the dictionary?